# Icons not centered within div? Align-item: center issue?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for putting my signature in the footer of a website: https://codepen.io/BarrieO/pen/ayQxoZ

However, when implemting the code on my Wordpress website (http://bartoml215.215.axc.nl/), the icons within the divs are not centered as in the Codepen. I think this has to do with the css property `align-items: center` for my `.icon-footer` class, but not sure?

To be clear: I want to allign the icons perfectly in the middle of the rounded squares, not in the bottom-middle as currenctly on the website. I want the same result as in the Codpen.

How come my icons are not alligned in the .icon-footers divs?

Comment: Where do want it to align to? its currently at the right side of the footer in the website!

Comment: @NarenMurali sorry for not being clear, I want the icons to be alligned perfectly in the middle of the rounded squares. The position within footer/website is fine.

Comment: @BarrieO don't you upvote or sth?! :\

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix. I tested it on your site.
I really prefer if you do this. but if you don't want this... go below..
note that for this to work you have to replace this code below with the "bottom-bar" div that you already have...

```
<div id="bottom-bar" class="solid-bg" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="wf-wrap">
        <div class="wf-container-bottom">
            <div class="wf-table wf-mobile-collapsed" style="
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
">

<div id="starter" class="icon-footer" style="
    transform: none;
    position: static;
    margin: auto;
">
      <img src="https://www.petasos.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/wingedHelmetSmall.png" class="petasos">
    </div>

</div>
        </div><!-- .wf-container-bottom -->
    </div><!-- .wf-wrap -->
</div>
```

ok the second solution:
just change this css selectors to what i have provided below:

```
#starter {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
    /* left: 215px; */
    /* transform: translate(-100%, -100%); */
    transition: all 0.6s linear;
    filter: invert(100%);
}
.iconHolder {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 57px; */
    width: 215px;
    /* right: 20px; */
}
```

[image: image of your page]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 modifications for it to work for your website:

1- Change the main `wingedHelmet` element class to `main-icon-footer`

```
<div id="starter" class="main-icon-footer ">
  <img src="https://www.petasos.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/wingedHelmetSmall.png" class="petasos">
</div>
```

2- Add the class `main-icon-footer` to your CSS file

```
.main-icon-footer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px #818181 solid;
}
```

3- Remove `align-items: center;` from `.icon-footer` in your CSS file

```
.icon-footer {
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 25%;
      background: white;
      border: 1px #818181 solid;
}
```

Comment: i don't see how this solves the issue! i tried this in the chrome browser. but it messes up the icon. the wings get out of the border!!

Comment: Yeah, it fixes the icons and messes the wings one. This is why the first step is to change the class of the wings icon component.  Then changing icon-footer class property.

Comment: the real problem is those positioning that he is doing. they are not really needed.